# Splashscreen with custom button and without auto hide in IONIC

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, splash-screen

I would like to implement splashscreen with a button and some text and background images. Here, splashscreen is not a single png file instead it is a complete page consists of various views and text. 
The splashscreen will not auto hide but if I click on the start button then it will launch the first page of the application.
Please let me know how to implement in ionic splashscreen with manual interaction to go to next page.

Thanks,

Comment: you can create a custom page(Landing page) with some text and a background image and a start button which rootPage redirects to.

Comment: Custom page would be splashscreen, I want to modify splashscreen with button. After I press button then it has to go to root page. Splashscreen should not auto hide.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add any interaction into a splashscreen!

But you could  ceate a start page which looks the same as the splashscreen and add that button. initially only the splashscreen is visible and after the splashscreen is disapearing the button gets visible inside the start page.

Comment: That means start page will be the root page that will get launched after splashscreen. So, always splashscreen needs to be added as a single png file. Splashscreen cannot be added as a separate ionic page.

Comment: splashscreen must always be an image!